# How does the partial pressure of oxygen relate to its concentration in water?

Tags: atmosphere, oceanography, water, oxygen, gas

I've read that the partial pressure of oxygen in water will be the same as the partial pressure of oxygen in the atmosphere, but that the saturation of oxygen in water is dependent on factors like salinity and temperature. If the partial pressure of oxygen in water is equal to its partial pressure in the atmosphere, how is it possible that the concentration of dissolved oxygen in water can vary?